# What is the derivative of the Softmax function AFTER subtracting the maximum value from each input?

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm using the Softmax function as the activation function for the last layer of a neural network I am trying to code up. The function takes in a vector of elements, $\vec{z}$, where the length of  $\vec{z}$ is $L$. The function returns the activation values of the neurons or a vector $\vec{a}$ also of length $L$. The function is:

\begin{equation}
a_j = \dfrac{e^{z_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^{L}e^{z_k}}
\end{equation}

$a_1$ would be the first element in $\vec{a}$, then $a_2$, until the last element is $a_L$. The values from $\vec{z}$ are exponentiated as to reduce their possible range to $(0,\infty)$. Dividing each of the exponentiated elements by the sum of all the exponentiated elements would then return values in a range of $(0,1)$.

Since $a_j$ is dependent on all the values of $\vec{z}$ -- the summation in the denominator includes all values of $\vec{z}$ -- we could think of $a_j$ as a function of each of the elements in $\vec{z}$, i.e. $a_j(z_1, z_2, z_3, ..., z_L)$. With this we can take a partial derivative with respect to one of the elements of $\vec{z}$, i.e. $\dfrac{\partial a_j}{\partial z_i}$ where $z_i$ is an arbitrary element of $\vec{z}$.

It can be shown that this derivative is dependent on whether $i=j$. [This page](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/) describes the derivation and shows that:

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial a_j}{\partial z_i} = a_j \left( \delta_{ij} - a_i\right) 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\delta_{ij} = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        1, & \text{if } i = j\\
        0, & \text{if } i\ne j
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}

**My question** is about subtracting the maximum of the vector before doing the Softmax function. If $\max(\vec{z}) = \hat{z}$, then the Softmax function would look like:

\begin{equation}
a_j = \dfrac{e^{z_j - \hat{z}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{L}e^{z_k-\hat{z}}}
\end{equation}

The reasoning behind doing this is to eliminate the possibility of an overflow error when exponentiating $z_j$. By subtracting the largest element from the vector from each of the elements, the largest value would now be $0$ and all other elements would be negative. When exponentiated this would then produce a possible range of $(0,1]$.

No resources that I found have showed that this subtraction preserves the derivative. I tried to derive this myself but got stuck when noticing that $\hat{z}$ is a function of the elements of $\vec{v}$, i.e. $\hat{z} = \max(z_1, z_2, z_3, ..., z_L)$. This in turn, allows a partial derivative to be taken such as $\dfrac{\partial \hat{z}}{\partial z_i}$. **I would like to understand how the original partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial a_j}{\partial z_i}$ is derived when subtracting the maximum value of the vector from each element.**

One thing that could *maybe* work is to do the chain rule. If we let $\overset{*}{z_i} = z_i-\hat{z}$, we could use the chain rule:

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial a_j}{\partial z_i} = \dfrac{\partial a_j}{\partial \overset{*}{z_i}} \dfrac{\partial \overset{*}{z_i}}{\partial z_i}
\end{equation}

This last chain rule is something that I found tricky to solve, and it might not even be a correct way of approaching this change to the Softmax derivative.